# SMTP 550 5.1.1 but mailbox exists

Tags: postfix, ldap, cyrus

I'm creating a mailbox on our Postfix server. We've a script which synchronize our LDAP to our Webmail (~RoundCube), and then we must execute the following command on the Postfix server:

```sh
echo -e "test@domain.tld\tOK" >> /etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox
echo -e "test@domain.tld\talias.test@domain.tld" >> /etc/postfix/virtual_alias # if we want an alias
postmap /etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox && postmap /etc/postfix/virtual_alias
/etc/init.d/postfix reload
```

This procedure used to work until last week and we're not able to explain/solve the issue.

Sending a test mail though the Webmail to the newly created mailbox returns:

```
<test@domain.tld>: host 127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1] said: 550-Mailbox unknown.  Either
    there is no mailbox associated with this 550-name or you do not have
    authorization to see it. 550 5.1.1 User unknown (in reply to RCPT TO
    command)
```

However, Postfix responds `250 2.1.0 Ok` to the `RCP TO:<test@domain.tld>` command:

```
$ nc our.mail.server.tld 25
220 our.mail.server.tld ESMTP Postfix (CentOS)
HELO domain.tld
250 our.mail.server.tld
MAIL FROM:<>
250 2.1.0 Ok
RCPT TO:<test@domain.tld>
250 2.1.0 Ok
DATA
Subject: testing
test email
.
250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 7E8B043
```

But the maillog indicates a `550 5.1.1 User unknow`... (log anonymized)

```
# edited following Nikita Kipriyanov recommendation 
Jul  8 15:07:36 srv postfix/smtp[30469]: > 127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024: RCPT TO:<test@domain.tld> ORCPT=rfc822;test@domain.tld
Jul  8 15:07:36 srv postfix/smtp[30469]: < 127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024: 250 2.1.5 Recipient <test@domain.tld> OK
Jul  8 15:07:37 srv postfix/smtpd[30492]: < localhost[127.0.0.1]: RCPT TO:<test@domain.tld> ORCPT=rfc822;test@domain.tld
Jul  8 15:07:37 srv postfix/smtpd[30492]: extract_addr: input: <test@domain.tld>
Jul  8 15:07:37 srv postfix/smtpd[30492]: smtpd_check_addr: addr=test@domain.tld
Jul  8 15:07:37 srv postfix/smtpd[30492]: send attr address = test@domain.tld
Jul  8 15:07:37 srv postfix/smtpd[30492]: input attribute value: test@domain.tld
Jul  8 15:07:37 srv postfix/smtpd[30492]: rewrite_clnt: local: test@domain.tld -> test@domain.tld
Jul  8 15:07:37 srv postfix/smtpd[30492]: send attr address = test@domain.tld
Jul  8 15:07:37 srv postfix/smtpd[30492]: input attribute value: test@domain.tld
Jul  8 15:07:37 srv postfix/smtpd[30492]: resolve_clnt: `' -> `test@domain.tld' -> transp=`lmtp' host=`127.0.0.1:24' rcpt=`test@domain.tld' flags= class=virtual
Jul  8 15:07:37 srv postfix/smtpd[30492]: ctable_locate: install entry key test@domain.tld
Jul  8 15:07:37 srv postfix/smtpd[30492]: extract_addr: in: <test@domain.tld>, result: test@domain.tld
Jul  8 15:07:37 srv postfix/smtpd[30492]: ctable_locate: leave existing entry key test@domain.tld
Jul  8 15:07:37 srv postfix/smtpd[30492]: milter_macro_lookup: result "test@domain.tld"
Jul  8 15:07:37 srv postfix/smtpd[30492]: ctable_locate: leave existing entry key test@domain.tld
Jul  8 15:07:37 srv postfix/smtpd[30492]: ctable_locate: leave existing entry key test@domain.tld
Jul  8 15:07:37 srv postfix/smtpd[30492]: milter8_rcpt_event: milter inet:127.0.0.1:8891: rcpt <test@domain.tld> ORCPT=rfc822;test@domain.tld
Jul  8 15:07:37 srv postfix/smtpd[30492]: event: SMFIC_RCPT; macros: {rcpt_addr}=test@domain.tld {rcpt_host}=127.0.0.1:24 {rcpt_mailer}=lmtp
Jul  8 15:07:37 srv postfix/lmtp[30505]: > 127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:24: RCPT TO:<test@domain.tld>
Jul  8 15:07:37 srv cyrus/lmtp[18927]: verify_user(user.test) failed: Mailbox does not exist
Jul  8 15:07:37 srv postfix/lmtp[30505]: send attr original_recipient = test@domain.tld
Jul  8 15:07:37 srv postfix/lmtp[30505]: send attr recipient = test@domain.tld
Jul  8 15:07:37 srv postfix/lmtp[30505]: send attr dsn_orig_rcpt = rfc822;test@domain.tld
Jul  8 15:07:37 srv amavis[23265]: (23265-17) Passed BAD-HEADER-7 {RelayedInternal}, MYNETS LOCAL [172.16.10.39]:2828 <> -> <test@domain.tld>, mail_id: nTFlKNl0Vr0b, Hits: 5.677, size: 300, queued_as: C7DB445, 1476 ms
Jul  8 15:07:37 srv postfix/smtp[30469]: 73B0143: to=<test@domain.tld>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=49, delays=48/0/0/1.5, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as C7DB445)
Jul  8 15:07:37 srv postfix/lmtp[30505]: C7DB445: to=<test@domain.tld>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:24, delay=0.11, delays=0.09/0/0/0.03, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (host 127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1] said: 550-Mailbox unknown.  Either there is no mailbox associated with this 550-name or you do not have authorization to see it. 550 5.1.1 User unknown (in reply to RCPT TO command))
```

Any idea about this behavior ? Why `RCPT TO` returns `250 2.1.5 Ok` whith netcat, but in the end stay stuck with a `550 5.1.1 User unknown` ?

---

master.cf

```
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
smtps     inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#628      inet  n       -       n       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    fifo  n       -       n       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      fifo  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     fifo  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       n       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       n       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       n       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       n       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
# When relaying mail as backup MX, disable fallback_relay to avoid MX loops
relay     unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
        -o smtp_fallback_relay=
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       n       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       n       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       n       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       n       -       1       scache

smtp-amavis unix -      -       n     -       8  smtp
    -o smtp_data_done_timeout=1200
    -o smtp_send_xforward_command=yes
    -o disable_dns_lookups=yes

127.0.0.1:10025 inet n  -       n     -       -  smtpd
    -o content_filter=
    -o local_recipient_maps=
    -o relay_recipient_maps=
    -o smtpd_restriction_classes=
    -o smtpd_delay_reject=no
    -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
    -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
    -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
    -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
    -o smtpd_data_restrictions=reject_unauth_pipelining
    -o smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions=
    -o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8,<other_valids_networks>
    -o smtpd_error_sleep_time=0
    -o smtpd_soft_error_limit=1001
    -o smtpd_hard_error_limit=1000
    -o smtpd_client_connection_count_limit=0
    -o smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit=0
    -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks,no_unknown_recipient_checks
```

Comment: You can temporary add 127.0.0.1 into `debug_peer_list`, for which Postfix daemons will execute with elevated log level. In the (greatly expanded) log it will explain how it interprets each configuration directive and this should give a clue where it fails. For now, I am sure how else to debug this, provided that you use a configuration which was "used to work" previously.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I've doing so and edited my answer. Could it be related to changes from our DNS records ? We're about to migrate our mailserver and the service providers we're working with may have already tweak the DNS.

Comment: Well that's odd. Please also post the `main.cf` file.

Comment: Wow, I noticed something. According to your log, 73B0143 is being successfully received via SMTP at port 10025 as C7DB445, but immediately that thing tries to inject it via LMTP to port 24 where it gets bounced. What are the things that listen at ports 10025 (which accepts via smtp and relays via lmtp) and 24 (which rejects via lmtp)?

Comment: Is that unusual ? I'm afraid we don't have enough knowledge to interpret this fact.
`smtpd` is listening port 10025 (with the options mentioned at the end of `master.cf`), and `[khelper]` port 24.

Comment: You mention ongoing migrations.. could someone have placed an empty LDAP server on the domain Cyrus was still directly fetching its users from?

Comment: `[khelper]` sounds more like a kernel thread and less like an LMTP service. Go look for *Cyrus* configuration, that is more likely what is listening on `24/tcp`

Answer (score 0):

**Postfix simply returns what it was told by the LMTP service it tried to hand the mail over for delivery. If the expanded alias is correct, you have to check *that* service, not (just) Postfix.**

---

Many things could have resulted in this scenario, but its fairly clear that the user/alias list of Postfix is no longer in sync with the user of the server Postfix passes the mailto (the detour via Amavis complicates the logs, but does not appear to be the problem).

**Next diagnose step: Compare the user list available to your MDA (*Cyrus IMAPd*, by the looks of the error message) to the actual result of your postfix virtual mappings.**

Query your postfix maps with these commands:

```
postmap -v -v -q test@domain.tld hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox
postmap -v -v -q test@domain.tld hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_alias
```

Querying like this is better than just trusting you executed the command correctly, because duplicates and typos are more obvious then. I *think* your setup generally only results in only *one* of the two maps.

Query the user list of the LMTP service using the information you'll find in its configuration to verify the mailbox really exists. To query the LDAP directly, use `ldapsearch -U .. -H ldaps://..`, to investigate specific servers use their provided utilities: for *Dovecot*, use `doveadm user ..` - for *Cyrus* use `cyrusadm info [name]`, ..

Consider also failure modes like the LDAP server where you are keeping your user list was temporarily or permanently unreachable by a server or maintenance script meant to fetch that data.

---

Your could have eased this and can still ease future debugging by adding suitable `syslog_name` options in your `master.cf` - that way you can more easily tell which of your (apparently multiple similar) services has logged which lines.

```
submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
 -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
 -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
 -o ...
...
smtps     inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
 -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
 -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
 -o ...
...
127.0.0.1:10025 inet n  -       n     -       -  smtpd
 -o syslog_name=postfix/description
 -o ...
```